# How do I visually "hg rebase --continue" in TortoiseHg Workbench after a Pull->Rebase operation?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using Mercurial and after I pull changesets from a remote repo, I do a rebase (to keep it easy to sync with SVN).

If there are merge conflicts during the rebase, I need to execute `hg rebase --continue` after I fix them up. This isn't a big deal, but I'd like a "visual" way to do this since I'm hoping to move my teammates to Hg and the command-line is too frictious for everyone to learn.

How can I execute the `continue` option during a rebase using only the TortoiseHg Workbench (v 2.2) GUI?

Comment: When you move your team mates to Hg, shouldn't you convert the SVN repository to Hg instead of keeping as SVN? If you do convert it, you won't need to rebase and your workflow will be more simple.

Comment: Good point, but we'll probably keep things backed with SVN for a while to give us a sort of "safety net"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In TortoiseHG you can do a whole rebase using GUI so you don't need to run `hg rebase` manually. Just right click on a revision and select `Modify history->Rebase...`.

If you already started rebase and want to run `rebase --continue` via GUI, just run TortoiseHG, right click on any revision and select `Modify history->Rebase...`. TortoiseHG will detect the unfinished rebase and will run `rebase --continue` automatically.

Comment: Yep, this worked like a charm. Odd that you have to right-click on a revision (any revision) to access this, however...

Comment: Also, have in mind that you need to activate rebase extension for hg for this menu to appear. You can do it in thg GUI too, simply go to settings dialog and then in extensions tab.

Comment: To use these options they must be enabled in the settings. Settings -> Extensions -> mq and rebase are both good.